# relatedTo a category in a matrix field

Tags: matrix, categories, relatedto

All, I'm very close, but missing something and any help is appreciated. I have a teamMember matrix block allowing me to add employees with some basic info. One of the fields is a category field called 'department'. I"m trying to list the departments, and within them, the employee information.

Currently my output is this:

```
Marketing
  marketing member one
  marketing member two
  creative member one
  creative member two

Creative
  marketing member one
  marketing member two
  creative member one
  creative member two
```

However, I'm looking to achieve this:

```
Marketing 
  marketing member one
  marketing member two

Creative
 creative member one
 creative member two
```

It seems that I'm doing something wrong with `relatedTo`.

My code:

```
        {# Fetch entries with a Matrix block to get non empty categories #}
        {% for block in entry.teamMember.all() %}
        {% set category = block.department.one() %}

        {# Fetch entries with a Matrix block related to the category #}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).all() %}

        <section id="{{ category.title }}">
            <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
            {% for block in entry.teamMember.all() %}
            <section class="member">
                {% set image = block.photograph.one() %}
                {% if image %}
                <div style="background-image: url('{{ image.getUrl('image500') }}');">&nbsp;</div>
                {% endif %}

                <h1>{{ block.fullName }} <em>{{ block.jobTitle|markdown }}</em></h1>
                {{ block.biography }}
            </section>
            {% endfor %}

        </section>
        {% endfor %}
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
    {# Fetch entries with a Matrix block to get non empty categories #}
    {% for block in entry.teamMember.all() %}
    {% set category = block.department.one() %}

    <section id="{{ category.title }}">
        {% if category.title != 'Ownership' %}<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>{% endif %}
        {% for block in entry.teamMember.relatedTo(category).all() %}
        <section class="member">
            {% set image = block.photograph.one() %}
            {% if image %}
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ image.getUrl('image500') }}');">&nbsp;</div>
            {% endif %}

            <h1>{{ block.fullName }} <em>{{ block.jobTitle|markdown }}</em></h1>
            {{ block.biography }}
        </section>
        {% endfor %}

    </section>
    {% endfor %}
```